# How to graph multiple lines of the same color that each contain multi-colored points

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I need to make a graph with multiple lines and points. Each line contains 3 points that should each be colored black, yellow, and red. The line should be a neutral gray.

I managed to create a graph that has those points without lines:

[image]

```
Graphics[
 Table[{Text[
    Style["•", Flatten[colors][[i]], Bold, 
     FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Arial"],
    data[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}], 
 ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Frame -> True]
```

And a graph that has those points connected by a line but colored incorrectly:

[image]

```
 ListLinePlot[Partition[data, 3], PlotMarkers -> {"•", 20}]
```

The data:

```
data = {{-0.962001,0.397816},{-0.122007,-0.0413612},{-0.0544419,-0.214962},{-0.135477,0.571107},{0.899526,0.190296},{0.898588,0.00546919},{-0.347618,0.666652},{0.246898,0.498308},{0.374387,0.483023},{-0.581681,0.14916},{-0.0997349,-0.10738},{0.0364981,-0.261247},{0.768949,0.875527},{1.95692,0.436888},{1.95962,0.355918},{-1.25323,0.307325},{-0.411717,-0.163014},{-0.387259,-0.196534},{-0.419625,0.287503},{-0.0076809,0.131083},{-0.0899933,0.17461},{0.0317604,-0.0695526},{0.370543,-0.260739},{0.513008,-0.325415},{0.424957,-0.103409},{0.94739,-0.363821},{1.24866,-0.520327},{-1.13206,0.149609},{-0.174019,-0.957962},{0.150149,-1.12718},{-1.10439,0.151338},{0.08283,-1.0489},{0.437483,-1.23367},{-1.13195,0.180468},{0.22697,-1.22584},{0.564093,-1.32619},{-1.12527,0.144753},{-0.31816,-0.769721},{0.13676,-1.08828},{0.512897,0.615075},{1.60425,0.266658},{1.56731,0.157649},{1.07963,0.691473},{2.32712,0.251782},{2.24102,0.203162},{0.146878,0.550012},{0.920199,0.229813},{0.93112,0.105877},{-0.618883,0.288482},{-0.114264,0.0952308},{-0.0902663,-0.0274716},{-0.42587,0.26112},{0.0296797,0.134414},{0.234351,0.0977336},{0.149234,0.312535},{0.566986,0.146658},{0.729692,0.192777},{-0.797245,0.301785},{-0.405653,0.129507},{-0.399827,0.125799},{-0.986633,0.301104},{-0.423614,-0.0630775},{-0.179002,-0.258728},{-1.06393,0.294462},{-0.646153,-0.0180542},{-0.530922,-0.174294},{-1.3346,0.288987},{-0.855399,-0.0954821},{-0.603291,-0.291644},{-0.953345,0.34497},{0.0734577,-0.507661},{0.495145,-0.806878},{-1.39286,0.27325},{-1.04882,-0.0124537},{-0.86758,-0.177823},{-1.07263,0.189348},{-0.87054,0.0332001},{-0.709255,-0.055134},{-0.884372,-0.133042},{-0.715605,-0.278561},{-0.450264,-0.591745},{0.00174907,0.689063},{0.857285,0.343011},{0.841798,0.233118},{0.268577,0.56418},{1.30903,0.0808955},{1.34309,-0.0496938},{-0.442908,0.205066},{0.156048,-0.103125},{0.229659,-0.2128},{-0.769446,0.115635},{-0.718515,0.0678925},{-0.687545,0.0584056},{-0.107299,0.0528954},{0.0258309,-0.0434246},{0.106836,-0.143284}}

colors = ConstantArray[{Black, Yellow, Red}, Length[repeatedStrainLabels]/3]
```

How can I get a graph that contains a gray line for every 3 elements in `data`, with the 1st element being a black point on the line, 2nd yellow, and 3rd red?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> {Black, Yellow, Red}, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], Epilog ->  {Gray, Line@Partition[data, 3]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPlot[Riffle[List /@ data, Partition[data, 3]], 
 Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotStyle -> Riffle[{Black, Yellow, Red}, Gray, {2, -1, 2}], 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of Epilog. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Graphics[{Gray, Line@#, AbsolutePointSize[4], Black, Point[#[[1]]], 
    Yellow, Point[#[[2]]], Red, Point[#[[3]]]} & /@ 
  Partition[data, 3], Axes -> True]
```

[image]